# React.PropsWithChildren with no props other than `children`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component with no props other than `children`, i.e.:

```
function Foo({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren<>) {}
```

`React.PropsWithChildren` requires an argument. If I do `React.PropsWithChildren<{}>`, Eslint produces `` Don't use `{}` as a type. `{}` actually means "any non-nullish value". ``.

I'm using this for the empty object type:

```
type EmptyObj = { [k: string]: never };
```

However, `React.PropsWithChildren<EmptyObj>` causes:

```
Type '{ children: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'EmptyObj'.
  Property 'children' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

What should I pass to `React.PropsWithChildren`?

**Edit:**

I know I can just do:

```
function Foo({ children }: { children?: React.ReactNode }) {}
```

However, I'm using `React.PropsWithChildren` throughout the codebase, so I'd prefer to keep it consistent.

Comment: Can you recreate the type error? You have some uncommon rule configured, I don't get any warnings even with an empty obj: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-benz-35y0l?file=/src/App.tsx:0-220

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using `typescript-eslint`

Comment: Alternatively you can also disable the eslint rule. Always surprising to me the hoops people sometimes jump through to make eslint happy. Eslint is supposed to make your code better. If you feel a rule doesn't, don't use that rule

Comment: It's a useful rule, it's Typescript that's making it frustrating

Comment: I'd argue consistency for its own sake, at the expense of clarity, doesn't make sense. Like, if there's a simpler approach (and you cite it) why not just use that? Instead, you encounter an ESLint warning because the type makes no sense, and you "solve it" (the accepted answer) using something that's even more complicated. If you were really married to `React.PropsWithChildren<{}>`, why not just silence the ESLint warning with a comment-pragma? Totally understand the desire to know how to do it, but then to actually do it... does not compute.

Comment: Maybe he likes complications.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The solution is:

```
function Foo({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren<Record<never, any>>) {}
```

If eslint warns you about type `any` use `Record<never, never>` instead.

Answer (score 25):

I was in the same situation and decided to go with:

```
PropsWithChildren<unknown>
```

**Update:**

See Jorrit's comment below, but React is [making that the default for PropsWithChildren](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/60641/files#diff-32cfd8cb197872bcba371f5018185d2e75fa540b52cda2dd7d8ac12dcc021299R799), which is now defined as `type PropsWithChildren<P = unknown> ...`. That means we can simplify the example below to:

```
const MyComponent = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => { /* ... */ }
```

We're declaring a component that accepts children, but we don't know (or don't care) about other props it may have.

**Example:**

```
const MyComponent = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<unknown>) => { /* ... */ }

// ...

<MyComponent>
  <span>children</span>
</MyComponent>
```

**Why not the FC type?**

The use of the `FC` type is discouraged. You can read more about it in this PR: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177

Comment: Since June 2022 it is no longer necessary to write `PropsWithChildren<unknown>` because [PR #60641][1] was merged that makes `unknown` the default value of the generic parameter to `PropsWithChildren`.


  [1]: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/60641

Comment: That's nice! With that we can probably do `const MyComponent = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => { /* ... */ }`

Comment: The `FC` type is no longer discouraged. It is now generic and doesn't include `children` props by default.

Answer (score 6):

You can just leverage the `FC` type as follows:

```js
const Foo: FC = ({ children }) => {
    return <div>{children}</div>;
};
```

If you really want to stick to `PropsWithChildren`, then use `PropsWithChildren<unknown>` instead of `PropsWithChildren<{}>`. The warning you get comes from `typescript-eslint` and can be turned off for those cases as another option.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know and have you defined the types of children that the FC will be taking? If so, could you not just have a union type that is passed in as the child prop value?

```
type FooChildren = ChildTypeOne | ChildTypeTwo | ChildTypeThree;
type FooProps = { children?: FooChildren[] };

function Foo({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren<FooProps>) {}
```

Also, isn't `ReactChildren` an interface itself? Why not use that in the function argument?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how `React.FC<>` implemented you can try:

```
interface WrapperProps<> {}

function App(props: React.PropsWithChildren<WrapperProps>) {
  return <div>{props.children}...</div>;
}
```

Comment: `eslint@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface` has the error "An empty interface is equivalent to `{}`"